# Laravel not inserting Auth::id into table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking to insert multiple column values into a table 'answers'. I'm inserting a question_id from questions table, which is being inserted successfully.

But it's not inserting the auth:user() id now, returning '0' in the table

answercontroller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\questions;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class answerController extends Controller
{
    public function store($question_id,Requests\answerAddRequest $request)
    {
        Auth::user()->questions()->findOrFail($question_id)->first()->answers()->create($request->all());
    }
}
```

If I remove the `questions()->findOrFail($question_id)->first()` part, it inserts the auth::id, but not with this, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Laravel automatically fills the foreign key when a model is created using related models.
Like if I split your query it will look as:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$question = $user->questions()->findOrFail($question_id)->first();
$question->answers()->create($request->all());
```

Here answers model is created by `$question` Model object so it will automatically fills the question_id but will not fill user_id as it is not creates using `$user`.

But if you write your code as:

```
$user->answers()->create($request->all());
```

It will automatically fill the user_id field.

**Update**

To fill question_id you can write as:

```
$inputs = $request->all();
$inputs['question_id'] = $question_id;
$user->answers()->create($inputs);
```

Comment: then how'll i insert question_id ?

Answer (score 0):

If user ID is in `answers` table, why don't you just do this:

```
$request->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$request->question_id = $question_id;
Answer::create($request->all());
```

This will create just one query and it's much more readable and maintainable. Keep it simple.

Comment: it's returning '0' for both now. The columns are people_id instead of user_id

Comment: Did you add all these fields in a `$fillable` array? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment  Yes you did, what does `dd($request->user_id, $request->question_id);` show you if you put it right before `Answer::`

Comment: yes this is what i have for answer's mode: `class answers extends Model
{
    protected $table='answers';
    protected $fillable=['answer','question_id','people_id'];
    protected $primaryKey='answer_id';`

Comment: It throws, '2' and an array for the question_id

Comment: Please post an array.

Comment: the output   `2
questions {#181 ▼
  #table: "questions"
  #primaryKey: "question_id"
  #fillable: array:3 [▼
    0 => "question"
    1 => "created_at"
    2 => "details"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "question_id" => 1
    "people_id" => 2
    "question" => "This is a question"
    "details" => "answer me!!"
    "created_at" => "2016-10-26 16:08:37"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #relations: []
}`

Comment: If `dd($question_id)` shows this, it seems you're using something else in addition to my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126789/discussion-between-jaskaran-singh-puri-and-alexey-mezenin).